# Calculate subset of matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

When I have two non-sparse matrices `A` and `B`, is there a way to efficiently calculate `C=A.T.dot(B)` when I only want a subset of the elements of `C`? I have the desired indices of `C` stored in CSC format which is specified [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csc_matrix).

Comment: As much as this is the programming community, you might want to check this over at the Math SO.

Comment: @jdotjdot: To me this is purely a programming question, with next to no math contents.

Comment: I check mathexchange and while making the tags for the post, it didn't have any the ones that would seem relevant like scipy and numpy or even sparse.

Comment: The answer to this question depends on: (i) how sparse is C, (ii) how large the dimensions of A and B are. Please specify.

Answer (score 2):

If you know in advance which parts of C you want and some of these parts are contiguous and rectangular regions*, then you can use the matrix algebra rules associated with the Multiplication of Partitioned Matrices ([1](http://www.math.nyu.edu/%7Eneylon/linalgfall04/project1/jme/index.htm)) or Block matrix multiplication ([2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix)) to speed up some of these calculations. So for example, you can use the same basic logic of @GaryBishop, but instead of having a list of 'i' and 'j' elements you have a list (or array) of four-tuples of i_start, i_end and j_start, j_end that define sub-matrices of C then you can use those indices (though rules established in those links) to figure out the the sub-matrices of A and B you need to solve for the desired blocks of C.

For a simple example, Say you only wanted the middle block of C, so we partition C into C1, C2, and C3 by row and all we care about is C2. If A^{T} is likewise partitioned into three sets of rows A1, A2, A3 then C2 = A2 * B. The idea generalizes to rectangles of any shape, it just requires different partitions of A and B to calculate. The idea is the same.

- -This is trivially true but you'd only get time savings if the regions are larger than single elements.

Comment: That's the same that I thought. I suspect the rows that constitute C2 and A2 might even be non-contiguous (discontinuous slice)

Comment: I think you are correct, they don't have to be contiguous, though the algebra might be a bit trickier. A non-contiguous A2 might be best thought of as elements of a finer partition, e.g.  A1 (out), A2a (in), A2b (out), A2C (in), A3(out) but with careful indexing and a good understanding of which elements you care about it may be faster to work with a non-contiguous subset directly then working with one piece of contiguous partition at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating on the coordinates using Python (GaryBishop's answer), you can have numpy do the looping, which constitutes a substantial speed-up (timings below):

```
def sparse_mult(a, b, coords) :
    rows, cols = zip(*coords)
    rows, r_idx = np.unique(rows, return_inverse=True)
    cols, c_idx = np.unique(cols, return_inverse=True)
    C = np.dot(a[rows, :], b[:, cols])
    return C[r_idx, c_idx]

>>> A = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
>>> B = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
>>> np.dot(A.T, B)
array([[100, 112, 124, 136, 148],
       [115, 130, 145, 160, 175],
       [130, 148, 166, 184, 202],
       [145, 166, 187, 208, 229]])
>>> sparse_mult(A.T, B, [(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 3)])
array([100, 145, 202, 208])
```

`sparse_mult` returns a flattened array of the values at the coordinates you provide as a list of tuples. I am not very familiar with sparse matrix formats, so I don't know how to define CSC from the above data, but the following works:

```
>>> coords = [(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 3)]
>>> sparse.coo_matrix((sparse_mult(A.T, B, coords), zip(*coords))).tocsc()
<4x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

This is a timing of various alternatives:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> a = np.random.rand(2000, 3000)
>>> b = np.random.rand(3000, 5000)
>>> timeit.timeit('np.dot(a,b)[[0, 0, 1999, 1999], [0, 4999, 0, 4999]]', 'from __main__ import np, a, b', number=1)
5.848562187263569
>>> timeit.timeit('sparse_mult(a, b, [(0, 0), (0, 4999), (1999, 0), (1999, 4999)])', 'from __main__ import np, a, b, sparse_mult', number=1)
0.0018596387374678613
>>> np.dot(a,b)[[0, 0, 1999, 1999], [0, 4999, 0, 4999]]
array([ 758.76351111,  750.32613815,  751.4614542 ,  758.8989648 ])
>>> sparse_mult(a, b, [(0, 0), (0, 4999), (1999, 0), (1999, 4999)])
array([ 758.76351111,  750.32613815,  751.4614542 ,  758.8989648 ])
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how this works but I can't get it to work. Why is np.dot(A.T, B) a 5 by 4 matrix? Shouldn't it be 4x2? Using your example I get a failure in the function on line "C = np.dot(a[rows, :], b[:, cols])", "index error: index (2) out of range (0<=index<1) in dimension 1"

Comment: @BKay B was of the incorrect size in the example, replace it with `B = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)` (edit submitted)

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the CSC business, and perhaps answering a simpler question than you are asking. Here is how I would compute a subset of the elements of C given a list of tuples of C index values.

Since you are evaluating C=A.T.dot(B) you are multiplying columns of A by columns of B. So,

```
for i, j in indexList:
    C[i, j] = np.dot(A[:,i], B[:,j])
```

I'm guessing that isn't what you're looking for but I find the simple answer sometimes helps clarify the question.

Comment: Yes this is more or less the method I'm using right now, but unfortunately the looping calls to np.dot() are very slow.