# Subset of a matrix multiplication, fast, and sparse

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Converting a collaborative filtering code to use sparse matrices I'm puzzling on the following problem: given two full matrices X (m by l) and Theta (n by l), and a sparse matrix R (m by n), is there a fast way to calculate the sparse inner product . Large dimensions are m and n (order 100000), while l is small (order 10). This is probably a fairly common operation for big data since it shows up in the cost function of most linear regression problems, so I'd expect a solution built into scipy.sparse, but I haven't found anything obvious yet.

The naive way to do this in python is R.multiply(X*Theta.T), but this will result in evaluation of the full matrix X*Theta.T (m by n, order 100000**2) which occupies too much memory, then dumping most of the entries since R is sparse.

There is a [pseudo solution already here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731405/calculate-subset-of-matrix-multiplication), but it is non-sparse in one step:

```
def sparse_mult_notreally(a, b, coords):
    rows, cols = coords
    rows, r_idx = np.unique(rows, return_inverse=True)
    cols, c_idx = np.unique(cols, return_inverse=True)
    C = np.array(np.dot(a[rows, :], b[:, cols])) # this operation is dense
    return sp.coo_matrix( (C[r_idx,c_idx],coords), (a.shape[0],b.shape[1]) )
```

This works fine, and fast, for me on small enough arrays, but it barfs on my big datasets with the following error:

```
... in sparse_mult(a, b, coords)
      132     rows, r_idx = np.unique(rows, return_inverse=True)
      133     cols, c_idx = np.unique(cols, return_inverse=True)
  --> 134     C = np.array(np.dot(a[rows, :], b[:, cols])) # this operation is not sparse
      135     return sp.coo_matrix( (C[r_idx,c_idx],coords), (a.shape[0],b.shape[1]) )

ValueError: array is too big.
```

A solution which IS actually sparse, but very slow, is:

```
def sparse_mult(a, b, coords):
    rows, cols = coords
    n = len(rows)
    C = np.array([ float(a[rows[i],:]*b[:,cols[i]]) for i in range(n) ]) # this is sparse, but VERY slow
    return sp.coo_matrix( (C,coords), (a.shape[0],b.shape[1]) )
```

Does anyone know a fast, fully sparse way to do this?

Comment: That operation is as sparse as it can be with a vectorized approach. It'd be interesting to split the offending line in three to see when is the Memory error happening, i.e. `aa = a[rows, :]; bb = b[:, cols]; C = np.dot(aa, bb)`. You don't need the `np.array` call, and as is, it actually makes a copy of the array, so it may even be the culprit of your memory error. Can you destroy `X` and `Theta` in the process of generating `R`?

Comment: My inputs a,b are np.matrix, so the result C[r_idx,c_idx] without the np.array is a 2D (n x 1) matrix instead of a 1D array. This caused an error in the sp.coo_matrix call, so I put the np.array in there. Converting to arrays beforehand might save some time though.

Comment: X and Theta are both full matrices, but I can't see why you'd want to destroy them? I'll note that while my matrix R is sparse, the sparsity pattern is such that every row has at least one entry, and every column has at least one entry, such that the result of the unique calls is the full range of m and n. This causes the np.dot result to be the full dense product of the two arrays we're trying to multiply sparsely. I tried defining aa and bb as you suggested and it died with the same error at 'C = ...' again. 

Maybe cython is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I profiled 4 different solutions to your problem, and it looks like for any size of the array, the [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) jit solution is the best. A close second is @Alexander's cython solution.

Here are the results (M is the number of rows in the `x` array):

```
M = 1000
function sparse_dense    took 0.03 sec.
function sparse_loop     took 0.07 sec.
function sparse_numba    took 0.00 sec.
function sparse_cython   took 0.09 sec.
M = 10000
function sparse_dense    took 2.88 sec.
function sparse_loop     took 0.68 sec.
function sparse_numba    took 0.00 sec.
function sparse_cython   took 0.01 sec.
M = 100000
function sparse_dense    ran out of memory
function sparse_loop     took 6.84 sec.
function sparse_numba    took 0.09 sec.
function sparse_cython   took 0.12 sec.
```

The script I used to profile these methods is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
from numba import autojit, jit, float64, int32
import pyximport
pyximport.install(setup_args={"script_args":["--compiler=mingw32"],
                              "include_dirs":np.get_include()},
                  reload_support=True)

def sparse_dense(a,b,c):
    return coo_matrix(c.multiply(np.dot(a,b)))

def sparse_loop(a,b,c):
    """Multiply sparse matrix `c` by np.dot(a,b) by looping over non-zero
    entries in `c` and using `np.dot()` for each entry."""
    N = c.size
    data = np.empty(N,dtype=float)
    for i in range(N):
        data[i] = c.data[i]*np.dot(a[c.row[i],:],b[:,c.col[i]])
    return coo_matrix((data,(c.row,c.col)),shape=(a.shape[0],b.shape[1]))

#@autojit
def _sparse_mult4(a,b,cd,cr,cc):
    N = cd.size
    data = np.empty_like(cd)
    for i in range(N):
        num = 0.0
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            num += a[cr[i],j]*b[j,cc[i]]
        data[i] = cd[i]*num
    return data

_fast_sparse_mult4 = \
    jit(float64[:,:](float64[:,:],float64[:,:],float64[:],int32[:],int32[:]))(_sparse_mult4)

def sparse_numba(a,b,c):
    """Multiply sparse matrix `c` by np.dot(a,b) using Numba's jit."""
    assert c.shape == (a.shape[0],b.shape[1])
    data = _fast_sparse_mult4(a,b,c.data,c.row,c.col)
    return coo_matrix((data,(c.row,c.col)),shape=(a.shape[0],b.shape[1]))

def sparse_cython(a, b, c):
    """Computes c.multiply(np.dot(a,b)) using cython."""
    from sparse_mult_c import sparse_mult_c

    data = np.empty_like(c.data)
    sparse_mult_c(a,b,c.data,c.row,c.col,data)
    return coo_matrix((data,(c.row,c.col)),shape=(a.shape[0],b.shape[1]))

def unique_rows(a):
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
    unique_a = np.unique(a.view([('', a.dtype)]*a.shape[1]))
    return unique_a.view(a.dtype).reshape((unique_a.shape[0], a.shape[1]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time

    for M in [1000,10000,100000]:
        print 'M = %i' % M
        N = M + 2
        L = 10

        x = np.random.rand(M,L)
        t = np.random.rand(N,L).T

        # number of non-zero entries in sparse r matrix
        S = M*10

        row = np.random.randint(M,size=S)
        col = np.random.randint(N,size=S)

        # remove duplicate rows and columns       
        row, col = unique_rows(np.dstack((row,col)).squeeze()).T

        data = np.random.rand(row.size)

        r = coo_matrix((data,(row,col)),shape=(M,N))

        a2 = sparse_loop(x,t,r)

        for f in [sparse_dense,sparse_loop,sparse_numba,sparse_cython]:
            t0 = time.time()
            try:
                a = f(x,t,r)
            except MemoryError:
                print 'function %s ran out of memory' % f.__name__
                continue
            elapsed = time.time()-t0
            try:
                diff = abs(a-a2)
                if diff.nnz > 0:
                    assert np.max(abs(a-a2).data) < 1e-5
            except AssertionError:
                print f.__name__
                raise
            print 'function %s took %.2f sec.' % (f.__name__,elapsed)
```

The cython function is a slightly modified version of @Alexander's code:

```
# working from tutorial at: http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html
cimport numpy as np

# Turn bounds checking back on if there are ANY problems!
cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn of bounds-checking for entire function
def sparse_mult_c(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] a,
                  np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] b,
                  np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] data,
                  np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim=1] rows,
                  np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim=1] cols,
                  np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] out):

    cdef int n = rows.shape[0]
    cdef int k = a.shape[1]
    cdef int i,j

    cdef double num

    for i in range(n):
        num = 0.0
        for j in range(k):
            num += a[rows[i],j] * b[j,cols[i]]
        out[i] = data[i]*num
```

Comment: I like that the numba solution is both faster AND doesn't require an external compilation step. FTW.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the extra information on the comments, I think what's throwing you off is the call to `np.unique`. Try the following approach:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d

n = 100000
x = np.random.rand(n, 10)
theta = np.random.rand(n, 10)
rows = np.arange(n)
cols = np.arange(n)
np.random.shuffle(rows)
np.random.shuffle(cols)


def sparse_multiply(x, theta, rows, cols):
    data = inner1d(x[rows], theta[cols])
    return sps.coo_matrix((data, (rows, cols)),
                          shape=(x.shape[0], theta.shape[0]))
```

I get the following timings:

```
n = 1000
%timeit sparse_multiply(x, theta, rows, cols)
1000 loops, best of 3: 465 us per loop

n = 10000
%timeit sparse_multiply(x, theta, rows, cols)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.29 ms per loop

n = 100000
%timeit sparse_multiply(x, theta, rows, cols)
10 loops, best of 3: 61.5 ms per loop
```

And of course, with `n = 100`:

```
>>> np.allclose(sparse_multiply(x, theta, rows, cols).toarray()[rows, cols],
                x.dot(theta.T)[rows, cols])
>>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested Jaime's answer yet (thanks again!), but I implemented another answer that works in the meantime using cython.

file sparse_mult_c.pyx:

```
# working from tutorial at: http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html
cimport numpy as np

# Turn bounds checking back on if there are ANY problems!
cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn of bounds-checking for entire function
def sparse_mult_c(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] a,
                  np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] b,
                  np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim=1] rows,
                  np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim=1] cols,
                  np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] C ):

    cdef int n = rows.shape[0]
    cdef int k = a.shape[1]
    cdef int i,j

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(k):
            C[i] += a[rows[i],j] * b[j,cols[i]]
```

Then compile it as per http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/tutorial.html

Then in my python code, I include the following:

```
def sparse_mult(a, b, coords):
    #a,b are np.ndarrays
    from sparse_mult_c import sparse_mult_c
    rows, cols = coords
    C = np.zeros(rows.shape[0])
    sparse_mult_c(a,b,rows,cols,C)
    return sp.coo_matrix( (C,coords), (a.shape[0],b.shape[1]) )
```

This works fully sparse and also runs faster than even the original (memory-inefficient for me) solution.